# Are Vertex Buffer Objects worth using in a purely quad/2d context?

Tags: opengl, vbo

Or would it be better to batch immediate mode calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditching immediate mode is always a good idea, but this doesn't mean you have to go through the full stretch of Vertex Buffer Objects. For a long time there have been Vertex Arrays (which form the foundation of Vertex Buffer Objects). You'll find that Vertex Arrays make a lot of things way easier, even for the "just drawing a few quads" case.

Answer (score 1):

VBOs are supported only by newer cards. Those cards won't have any problem rendering simple scene using OpenGL 1.1. Unless you are rendering a lot of primitives, there is no reason to use VBOs.

Comment: How do you define "newer" cards? Even my grandpa of GPUs, my faithfull GeForce2 of 1999 can do VBOs.

Comment: @datenwolf: Many Intel cards, still in use, don't support VBOs.

Comment: Intel GPUs hardly benefit from VBOs -- they are shared memory designs that use part of the regular system memory. Using regular Vertex Arrays thus are about as performant on them.  +++ Alas, it depends on the plattform and the driver used: On Linux VBOs are supported by Intel GPUs just fine.